# Is there any other way other then Response.Write which can declare html code inside?

Tags: vb.net

Cause when I use `Response.Write`, the html code appear above my form which I want it to be at the top.

Comment: For example Response.Write("<html code>") I put it at the backend but when I run the page display the Response.Write rather than displaying the form 1st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ASP literal in the .aspx page:

`<asp:Literal ID="MyLiteral" runat="server">`

And then in the code behind:

`MyLiteral.Text = "The HTML or text you want to appear where MyLiteral is."`

To append to it, use the += operator:

`MyLiteral.Text = "<table><tr><td>First cell</td>"
 MyLiteral.Text += "<td>Second cell</td></tr></table>"`

Comment: Hi @TonyHinkle I tried using it but it does not display anything.

Comment: Literal1.Text = "<td>"
                Literal1.Text = "<div align='center'><a href='Qty.aspx?id=" & tableDt.Rows.Item(count).Item("pic_name") & "&cachebust=<%=Now%>'>"
                Literal1.Text = "<font size='2' face='Verdana><b><img src='" & tableDt.Rows.Item(count).Item("Pic_Path") & "' border='0' alt='" & tableDt.Rows.Item(count).Item("table_Desc") & "'><br>"

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about exactly what you are doing.  Are you sure that the code where you are assigning Literal1.Text is running?  Have you put a break point there and run it in debug mode to see what the value of Literal1.Text is after it runs?  Also, each time you have a `Literal1.Text = "something"` line, it completely resets it and what you had in the previous line is gone.  If you are trying to concatenate all of this text.  Use `Literal1.Text +=` after the first time so that it will append to it, not overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks it show me something. I totally forgot to += .

Comment: Great--you'll love using literals now.  It's so easy to just crank out whatever you want onto the page wherever you want.